# How to use single `User Store` with multiple WSO2 products

Tags: wso2, wso2-as, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am planning to use `WSO2 ESB`, `WSO2 IS` and `WSO2 AS` for my project. My thought is to Use single JDBC userstore with IS for all user management.

Is it mandatory to have user store configured for other `ESB` and `AS` instance and what is the best approach for communicating each other?

Pointing to any related material will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Communicating each other for login? Do you mean Single Sign On?

Comment: I want to have authentication/authorization in `IS` only. The flow is like below: a) All Requests will come to `ESB` b)ESB will connect to `IS` for Authentication c)If Authentication succeed, connect `ESB` will connect to `AS` for executing actual service. Is there any reference architecture like this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to configure a user store for each of the servers, it's fine if you just want to have an admin user within the embedded user store to manage each server. Maybe later in a production environment you want to re-consider this.

Then if you use IS for identity management, it is better if you configure an external user store, for instance JDBC, for reliability and performance reasons. You could even configure the ESB and AS to point to the same user store, but you don't have to.

If you need authorization, there is a good example [here](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/08/finegrained-authorization-restful-services-xacml/)

Then if you want to use IS for authentication, it depends if we are talking about a web app, web services or APIs... there are different mechanisms you could use (SAML, OAuth..) depending on your requirements, and regardless of the user store you are using.

Comment: I am using a common JDBC UserStore for IS, AS and ESB now. My requirement is to use IS for authentication through REST services.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done. It is clearly explained in this [tutorial of WSO2 IS](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS410/Enabling+SSO+for+WSO2+Servers).
All you need to do is update carbon.xml files of each WSO2 product and change offset value to run on different ports. Then enable SSO on authenticators.xml of each WSO2 product.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this latest [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+SSO+for+WSO2+Servers) which clearly mentions the necessary steps to configure your scenario. This is applicable for latest WSO2 products.